# Change CSV name in Rails without respond_to block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I have a button that allows users to download a csv in my Rails 3.2 app.

## view

```
<%= link_to "Export registration data", learn_registrants_path(format: "csv", :id => @event.id), :class => "btn btn-default btn-primary" %>
```

## controller

```
 def export_registrants
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    if current_learner.id == @event.registration_contact_id
      registrants = EventRegistration.includes.where(event_id: @event.id)
      csv = RegistrantsExport.new(registrants).to_csv
      render text: csv
    end
  end
```

With the code above the csv file that gets downloaded is named `learn_registrants.csv`. I would like to add the event_id to the csv name. I found a `filename:` option that is used in a respond to block, but I can't use that here. Any ideas on how I can change the csv name without refactoring to use a respond_to block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `send_data` instead:

```
send_data csv, :filename => 'your_file_name.csv', 
    :disposition => 'inline', :type => "multipart/related"
```

Or you can change the file name by altering the header

```
headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"#{filename}\""
```

Comment: Thanks @jumpingcode. Setting the header worked like a charm.

Comment: Great news, glad to help